# Java sick GUI that does not pertain to look and feel?

Tags: java, user-interface, paint

I wanted to know how people make these sick GUI's in java?

I know how to make the standard crappy one with a nice background, but that is it.

Basically what I am talking about is it looks like they took photoshop and designed the entire GUI and then painted it to the screen and added buttons and stuff to it that they also made in photoshop. How do I do this and what am I looking for?

Of course I still want the same functionality... haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use a nice look and feel like Nimbus.
2. Use layout managers wisely
3. Learn about Painting Gradients
4. Learn about what colors look well together.